# Insert UUID vs UUID via Trigger - Performance

Tags: mysql, triggers, uuid

I understand that there are lots of threads and information about whether you should use UUIDs for PKs or anywhere for that matter. That is NOT my question.

Assuming, we have a table that has a varchar(36) column to store UUIDs. My question is simple, which is better if we assume that the app doesn't care which way it is done:

1) Place a new UUID into each row via a trigger on the table

OR

2) Insert the new UUID into each row directly via the insert query using the UUID() function  such as 
"insert into mytable values (UUID())"
or
"set @var=UUID(); insert into mytable values (@var);

MySQL 5.7.x if it matters.

Comment: You Auto Increment for Primary / Foreign Keys for relational. But if you still want to use UUIDs, you can try 2nd approach. Note : Performance will effect adversily when DB becomes larger.

Answer (score 0):

Just go with the second option. It makes no sense to do a job you can  directly and easily do in an insert query with a trigger. You will still be calling the UUID function in the trigger. The first is a little complex than the second, it won't help boost performance.

The first method makes use of the DRY (Don't Repeat Yourself) principle, which is a good programming practice. It also ensures that the all the IDs are really UUIDs.